# Real backend for my students?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I'd like each of my students to run at least one program (however trivial) on a real quantum computer. They can each sign up for accounts on ibm-q-experience. The question is, which of the backends are real and which are simulations? I see the word "simulation" in some of their names. Does that mean that any backend without the word "simulation" in its name is a real quantum computer?

Answer (score 3):

The online simulator is called the `ibmq_qasm_simulator`, all other devices with city names, e.g. `ibmq_vigo`, are real quantum devices.